# Show/Hide elements in a table

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to hide and show an entire column in a table depending on if a user has pressed a checkbox or not. Hiding the elements is easy, but showing them again later is a problem. I want them to be displayed exactly as they were before I hide them but thats not the case.

When I show the elements They are shown in a similar fashion (note that it doesn't add the rowspan, but thats how its displayed).

**Edit**
Also the below table is an example and is not the real table, its just for explaining purpose.

```
<TABLE BORDER=2 CELLPADDING=4>
<TR>
    <TH ROWSPAN=6 BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">Production</TH>
    <TD>Raha Mutisya</TD> 
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Shalom Buraka</TD> 
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Brandy Davis</TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Claire Horne</TD> 
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Bruce Eckel</TD> 
    </TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Danny Zeman</TD> 
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

And I want it to show in its original fashion like below.

```
<TABLE BORDER=2 CELLPADDING=4>
<TR>
    <TH BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">Production</TH>

    <TD>Raha Mutisya</TD> 


    <TD>Shalom Buraka</TD> 

    <TD>Brandy Davis</TD>

    <TD>Claire Horne</TD> 

    <TD>Bruce Eckel</TD> 

    <TD>Danny Zeman</TD> 
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

So my question is what "display" property should I use in this case? I have tested many of them but none suited my situation.

Below is the javascript code.

```
    $("#officialCheckBox").click(function() {
        if(this.checked && dataCol.Official ==="False"){
            table.setBodyColumnCss(column + 1, "hide_class");
        }
        else{
            table.setBodyColumnCss(column,"show_class");
        }              
    });

table.setBodyColumnCss(column,"show_class");

    this.setBodyColumnCss = function(col,css){
        col_css[col] = css;
        this.table_body.find("td[col=" +col+ "]").addClass(css);
    };
```

And the css classes.

```
.hide_class{
    display: none;
}
.show_class{
    display: inherit;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: could you add a sketch how it sould look before and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, to hide a row, apply the `hide_class` css class.  To reshow it again, don't add the `show_class` css class, instead, **remove** the previously added `hide_class` css class.
Also, I suggest you name your css classes `hide` and `show` rather than `hide_class` and `show_class`.

Comment: It was so simple, I feel so stupid. Many thanks. Will accept your answer in 4 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to add `.show_class`, so you don't have to worry about what value to chose for the display property (by the way, I think that the right value it's `table-cell`). Simply add or remove `.hide_class`.

Try something like this:

```
$("#officialCheckBox").click(function(){
    if(this.checked && dataCol.Official ==="False"){
        table.hideBodyColumn(column + 1);
    }
    else{
        table.showBodyColumn(column);
    }              
});

this.hideBodyColumn = function(col){
    this.table_body.find("td[col=" +col+ "]").addClass('hide_class');
};
this.showBodyColumn = function(col){
    this.table_body.find("td[col=" +col+ "]").removeClass('hide_class');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use and JS,

Just Use CSS and your task is achieved..

CSS:

```
table.tbl{
    display:table;
}
table.tbl tr td{
    display:table-row;
}
```

Here I have given class name `.tbl` to the given table.

Note: The Cell will loose the margin/padding as it is calculated by `display:table-cell` tag defined inside the `table-row` tag. ..

Check the working [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/Kft6h/1/)